# Необходимо завернуть код в (не void) метод, не используя в нем Console

Tags: c#

Код выводит числа от 10 до N, если сумма четных цифр больше нечетных

/// код:

```
        int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 10; i < N; i++)
        {

            int Oddsum = 0;
            int Evensum = 0;
            int check_i = i;

            while (check_i > 0)
            {
                int dights_i = check_i % 10;
                if (dights_i % 2 == 0) Evensum += dights_i;
                else
                    Oddsum += dights_i;

                check_i /= 10;
            }

            if (Evensum > Oddsum) Console.WriteLine($"{i}: {Evensum}");
            // необходимо чтобы в методе output был таким же.
```

// мой метод:

```
    public static string task09 (int A)
    {

        for (int i = 10; i <= A; i++)
        {
            int Oddsum = 0;
            int Evensum = 0;
            int check_i = i;

            while (check_i > 0)
            {
                int dights_i = check_i % 10;
                if (dights_i % 2 == 0) Evensum += dights_i;
                else
                    Oddsum += dights_i;

                check_i /= 10;
            }
            if (Evensum > Oddsum) return ($"|{i}: {Evensum}|, ");

        }
        return "";
```

Comment: Этот код не работает?

Comment: Из-за требования в не void-методах ставить return после каждого цикла. Не знаю как можно это обойти. Сам код работает, проблема с методом...

Comment: ну возвращайте `string` или `List<String>`  и каждый выхов вместо `console.writeline` пишите строку в `myStringBuilder.ApendLine(..)` или `myListOfStrings.Add(..)` , какие проблемы то? Причем тут return вообще?

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: Если ответ был полезен, чтобы принять его, вы можете поставить зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смысл задачи в том, чтобы не производить вывод прямо в методе.

У вас что-то типа этого.

```cs
private void Sum(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a + b;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Вызывается оно вот так

```cs
Sum(40, 2);
```

В консоль выводится `42`.

А надо вот так

```cs
private int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a + b;
    return result;
}
```

А вызывать например вот так.

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Sum(40, 2));
```

Или так.

```cs
int sum = Sum(40, 2);
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Результат работы точно такой же как с `void`.

То есть метод должен вернуть результат своей работы в вызывающий код, а не выводить в консоль или куда-то.